# multiprocessing: Run through an array with multiple processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-2.x

How to run through an array with multiple processes (for example 2) in parallel?
For example I have this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time, os

n=Value('i', 0)

l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def fun():
  try:
        while True:
            #time.sleep(0.01)   not used, explanation below
            print os.getpid(), l[n.value]
            n.value+=1
  except:
        return

for i in range(2):
    p=Process(target=fun)
    p.start()
```

Expected output should be like:

```
111 1
112 2
111 3
112 4
111 5
```

But I'm getting:

```
111 1
111 2
111 3
111 4
111 5
```

Only one process is running through an array.

I'm getting expected result only by putting `time.sleep()` with any very small value, but I'm looking for solution without it, if possible.

Comment: The output continues on like that?  
(i.e. always 111)?

Comment: @information_interchange if there is no sleep - yes, only one process is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your task executes so quickly the first process executed finishes before the second one even gets started. This is why putting the call to `sleep()` "fixes" things—it's because it slows the task down enough to give second time enough time to start, so they can both run concurrently for a while

You can see this with your code if you make the `l` list a lot larger, say `l = range(1, 1001)`.

To further illustrate this, below is a modified version of your code that also shows that eventually both of them will be running at the same time. It also prints out a little more information about what is occurring within each task:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time, os

n = Value('i', 0)
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def fun(cycles):
    assert cycles >= 0
    while cycles:
        try:
            while True:
                with n.get_lock():
                    print os.getpid(), l[n.value]
                    n.value += 1
        except IndexError:
            print('list index out of range exception occurred, resetting "n"')
            with n.get_lock():  # Reset for another cycle
                n.value = 0
        except Exception as exc:
            print('unexpected exception {} occurred'.format(exc))
            break
        cycles -= 1

    print('{} task terminating'.format(os.getpid()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cycles = 100
    for i in range(2):
        p = Process(target=fun, args=(cycles,))
        p.start()

    print('done')
```

Comment: This would seem to explain it, I was thinking of a lack of context switch/processor scheduling issue

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to put brackets here to in question. Btw on pc it's already calling start() and still not working as expected. Edited

Comment: Works for me on a Windows PC.

Comment: Hmmm... Can it be some PC issue? I'm running linux

Comment: On Ubuntu, I get the output:done
13978 1
13978 2
13978 3
13978 4
13978 5
13978 exception occurred: list index out of range
13979 exception occurred: list index out of range

Comment: Seems you didn't understand it well. I want every process to run function and increment shared value so output should be same as I wrote at "Expected output should be like:"

Comment: I understand what you _want_. The results are likely because of overhead of task switching verses the fact that the target processes have an extremely tight loop running almost continuously that is causing the them to behave as they do. This would also explain why adding a small amount of `sleep()` to the tight loop helps.

Comment: If you make `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` longer by using say, `l = range(1, 1001)`, you'll see from the output that both processes _are_ running at the same time but the tight loop means you have to give them more work to do before they quit due to the exception or the first will finish even before there's a chance to start the other one.

Comment: So, what you want to say is that in this case putting time.sleep() (or any other functionality that takes time) is the only possible way. Ok thats an answer I think